# error in declaring the class type variable

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
private:
    int x;
public:
    A(){
        x=0;
    }
    A(int i)
    {
        x=i;
    }
    int Get_x(){
        return x;
    }
};
class B{
    private:
    A objA(1);
    public:
    objA.Get_x();   
};
```

This is my code and it has two classes i.e A and B ..First class runs fine but in class B ..compiler gives the syntax error in the declaration of objB.....But as far as i know it should be correct ...so plz help ....thanks

Comment: What's the error it gives?

Comment: You're calling `objA.Get_x();` in the middle of a class declaration, outside of any functions or methods. What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 1):

This initialization is invalid for a data member:

```
A objA(1);
```

You need

```
A objA{1};
```

or

```
A objA = A(1);
```

Besides that, this kind of statement can only happen inside of a function:

```
objA.Get_x();
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is trying to interpret `A objA(1)` as a function declaration, which is wrong. You may declare objA as `A objA = A(1);` (please note that thi is a C++11 feature, you may need to enable it before).

Also, I don't really know what `objA.Get_x()` should do, but this is also wrong, you can't just access a member outside of a function. Probably, you meant this:

```
int Get_x() {
    return objA.Get_x();
}
```